# Defining derivatives in Real/Complex Analysis?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, limits, functions, derivatives

When studying Real Analysis, I was given the following definition for derivatives:

> Let $f:D \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, where $D$ is some subset of $\mathbb{R}$ and $a \in D$ be a cluster point of $D$ (For each $\epsilon > 0$ there is an $x \in D$ with $0<|x-a|<\epsilon$). Then $f$ is differentiable at $a$ if $\lim_{x\rightarrow a} \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$ exists and in this case we denote the limit $f'(a)$

And then in Complex Analysis, I have the following definition:

> Take $U \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ open, a function $f:U \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ and $c \in U$. Then $f$ is complex differentiable at $c$ if $\lim_{z\rightarrow c} \frac{f(z)-f(c)}{z-c}$ exists and we write $f'(c)$ for this limit

My question is, why is $U$ required to be open in the complex case, but $D$ is not required to be open in the real case? I can see that if $U$ is an open set, then each $c \in U$ is a cluster point of $U$, but it seems that having the domain $U$ be an open set in the complex case is a much stricter condition than in the real case where you only require that the individual point in question $a \in D$ is a cluster point of $D$. Why is this condition necessary in the complex case?

Comment: It is merely convenience, I would say. The whole power of holomorphic functions is only available if a function is differentiable in some open set. Defining the derivative at a cluster point is simply not useful.

Comment: "The whole power of complex differentiability is only available if a function is differentiable in some open set." -  Would it be possible for you to explain this further please?

Comment: Have a look at the first paragraph in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holomorphic_function: (emphasis added) “The existence of a complex derivative **in a neighbourhood** is a very strong condition: it implies that a holomorphic function is infinitely differentiable and locally equal to its own Taylor series (analytic). Holomorphic functions are the central objects of study in complex analysis.”

Comment: I don't think the concept is useful even in the real case except for right-hand and left-hand derivatives at the end points of an inrerval.

Comment: Thank you very much Martin. I'll read more about these concepts.

Comment: To be frank with you, I have never seen a real analysis textbook give such a definition for the real derivative. As far as I understand, defining the derivative of $f$ at a cluster point $p$ of $D$ only helps for defining the right-derivatives and left-derivatives at the endpoints of a closed interval, but almost everywhere in the literature, I have only seen the requirement that $D$ be an open set, making the definition completely analogous to that of complex differentiability. I do not know why we would care about cluster points of $D$ that are not themselves elements of $D$ if $D$ is open.

Comment: The definition isn't from a textbook, it's from the Lecture notes from the Real Analysis Course at my University (And the second definition is from the Lecture notes from the Complex analysis Course). Since the notes are written by different lecturers, I suppose they use different conventions when defining these concepts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Complex analysis is about [holomorphic functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holomorphic_function), and that are functions which are complex differentiable in *every point of an open set* in $\Bbb C$ (or $\Bbb C^n$). From that Wikipedia article (emphasis mine):

> The existence of a complex derivative **in a neighbourhood** is a very strong condition: it implies that a holomorphic function is infinitely differentiable and locally equal to its own Taylor series (analytic). Holomorphic functions are the central objects of study in complex analysis.

[Cauchy's integral theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_theorem) makes use of the differentiability in open sets. [Cauchy's integral formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula) is a consequence of that theorem, and [implies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula#Consequences) the *infinite* differentiability of holomorphic functions:

> The integral formula has broad applications. First, it implies that a function which is holomorphic in an open set is in fact infinitely differentiable there. Furthermore, it is an analytic function, meaning that it can be represented as a power series.

So while it would be possible to define the complex derivative at a cluster point of a (not necessarily open) domain, it is not useful. One cannot build a theory on that definition.

*A simple example:* The function $f: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$, $f(x) = |x|^3$ is differentiable. If we consider $D = \Bbb R$ as a subset of $\Bbb C$ then every $a\in D$ is a cluster point of $D$,   and $\lim_{x\to a} \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$ exists for every point $a \in D$. But $f$ is not analytic at the origin, it cannot be developed into a Taylor series, and it is not infinitely often differentiable.

Comment: It's certainly true that things are nicest when the derivative exists throughout a neighborhood, but the definition being asked about is just for the derivative existing at a single point in the interior of the domain. I think this question has a different answer which I will post shortly.

Answer (score 0):

> Why is this condition necessary in the complex case?

As Martin R pointed out in another answer, it's *not* necessary. I think the real question is "why is the definition phrased this way in many complex analysis texts", and I think the answer is primarily a *pedagogical* one.

In a first course on complex analysis, it's often not assumed that students have studied real analysis or significant topology. It's simpler and more accessible to give a definition of derivative that doesn't require students to engage with questions about multivariable real limits when there is not an entire disk around the point in the domain, especially when introductory calculus texts are a bit inconsistent about whether or not such limits exist.

Comment: Perhaps this is true, but as I wrote in my comment to the question, I have never seen a real analysis textbook refer to cluster points of the domain of the function in question. Almost everywhere in the literature, the requirement that U be open exists for real differentiability as well as complex differentiability. This particular textbook is probably just outlier in this regard. I also have no idea why cluster points would be of any interest in a real analysis course with regards to differentiability.

Comment: This makes sense to me because it does seem 'nicer' to consider the concept of limits at points in an open set rather than at cluster points.

Comment: I do not agree with this explanation. Requiring complex differentiability in open sets *is necessary* for the theory of complex analysis. It is not just for pedagogical reasons, to make the definition “simpler” or “more accessible.”